# Excel VBA Split a large array into multiple smaller arrays based on criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Let's say we have a large array pulled from a range, snippet of the spreadsheet below:

[image: I want to split the large array into multiple]

Lets assume the "Power Source" is at A1 and the bottom right cell is D8 for clarification.

I want to pull this information into an array, and then split this array into multiple smaller arrays based on their "Power Source". Each array keeping their respective rows. The second problem I face is that the number of "Power Sources" is dynamic. I could count the number of unique names but I'm not sure how to dynamically define arrays using that information.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub ArraySplitter()
Dim Arr1 as variant
Arr1=ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D8")
'Somehow split the array into a dynamic number of multiple small arrays
End Sub
```

Comment: The quickest method is to simply loop and load the other arrays with the data.

Comment: Loop over the array and use a scripting dictionary to count the number of times you see each value in the first column.

Comment: Also just search around for "dynamic range+VBA" to learn how to change your range every time instead of using a "magic range" (`"A1:D8"`).

Comment: What do you want to do with these arrays?  In Power Query (available in Excel 2010+), it is trivial to **GroupBy** Power Source.